# Ubuntu unable to detect 'Realtek RTL8188CE Wireless'

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

I'm trying the 64bit Ubuntu 12.04 on my new laptop to see if I'd like to get rid of Windows 8. The problem is that it's not detecting my wireless. It works in Windows 8, but won't work in Ubuntu.. I opened the terminal
and typed in:

```
iwconfig
```

I get the msg:

```
lo no wireless extensions.
```

I typed:

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

which didn't give any response. Then I typed:

```
sudo  lshw -C network
```

as advised in some forums. Still, it's not detecting the wireless. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: identify the wireless card, from windows if necessary. we need the chip name.

Comment: This is what shows up under network adapters:

Comment: Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter, Qualcomm Atheros AR8162/8166/8168 PCI-E Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30), and Realtek RTL8188CE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC

Comment: There is a long thread on the forums about this driver http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604101

Comment: How do I find out about the chip? Do you mean the processor chip? it's amd a8

Comment: No, the wireless chip, it is a Realtek RTL8188C, see the forums thread as there is no single solution and you will likely need a wired connection to install build-essential and download the wireless driver.

Comment: I'll go through both of the forums, but I don't have a wired connection. Is there a single solution or few I can choose from that don't require a wire?

Comment: Finding a wired connection is going to be easiest. Otherwise you have to use a tool such as aptoncd and download and manually install the packages.

Comment: Can you direct me or give me the link to the steps for aptoncd? I don't have a wire atm

Comment: http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/342076/169736