# Problems with attempting to install drivers. Ubuntu 12.04, Realtek

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, realtek

I just recently installed 12.04 LTS on my machine. It's dual boot with Windows 7 on the other side.While on Windows I have a solid connection with full bars all day long. However, on the Ubuntu side, I have 3 out of 4 bars, and the connection is constantly dropping.It only disconnects for a second or two, but in doing so, it disconnects my VPN. So I have to monitor my wifi icon.

My machine is Toshiba Satellite L755

I tried    `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off`    in terminal , but i get this:

Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.

After going to system settings>additional hardware drivers I get "No proprietary drivers are in use on this system"

When I run `sudo lspci` and I get these results:

```
Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
```

So I downloaded latest driver from Realtek website, copied to desktop, and extracted it.
In terminal i run
`sudo apt-get install gcc build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
for necessary dependencies. I then enter
`cd ~/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013`
`make`
`make install`

[image: Command Terminal read out.]At this point I get a long scroll with a few mentions of error1 and error 2. I try to reboot the computer with
`sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee`
but it says it cannot be found. So I manually reboot, and nothing changes under "Additional Drivers" scan. 
So I can't tell if I'm not installing correctly, or if there is something else going on.

Sources I've used so far:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2162026

[step by step Ubuntu 12.04 install of Realtek RTL8188CE driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342076/step-by-step-ubuntu-12-04-install-of-realtek-rtl8188ce-driver)

Here's what I get after entering

```
cd ~/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013

make clean
```

in the terminal:
[image: Make clean prompt]
 Ok. After following the steps in the answer provided by Chili555 below, I believe everything went smoothly. It's worth stating that after entering the

```
sudo modprobe rtl8192ce
```

command, nothing happened. So I rebooted manually. I now have all bars lit up in my wifi icon (as opposed to before, when I only had 3)

Chili555 put up a text file in the comment section below that shows what it should look like when entering the 4 lines of code in gedit. That was very helpful. Also, be mindful of where your directory is when entering a command in terminal for cleaning up download. I specified "desktop" because that's where my extracted zip was located.

EDIT: THE NEXT DAY, Well after spending the evening on Ubuntu, I found that I am still in the same boat as before. I still have not been able to fix this issue of intermittent disconnects.

Comment: You can just copy&paste text from the terminal - please don't use screenshots for that. Make sure you format it properly using the `<$>` button in the editor toolbar.

Comment: It works ! with sudo modprobe rtl8188ee for me.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

First, let's clean up the file from your first attempt:

```
cd Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013
make clean
```

Now, let's modify one file:

```
gedit pci.h
```

At the top of the file,after the comment section all out lined in ******, add this sequence:

```
#ifndef __devinit
#define __devinit
#define __devinitdata
#endif
```

Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. Now do:

```
make
sudo make install
```

Finally, I believe the driver you need is rtl8192ce and not rtl8188ee:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8192ce
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: I copied and pasted the first command you have, and hit enter. I get " No rule to make target 'clean'. Stop"  What am I missing? Am I misunderstanding how to enter it in command terminal? Thanks

Comment: Are you in the correct directory? ~/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013  If you list the contents of the directory, do you see the Makefile?: ls

Comment: Ok, I just edited my question. You're right, I had to not just copy and paste, but specify desktop. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Please proceed.

Comment: One last thing, sorry, but I entered the code in pci.h. Just want to make sure I am entering in the right spot, as well as should I delete the 2 pieces of line that was there before? Could you have a peak at my edit? Thanks again

Comment: Here is what the first several lines of the file should look like: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6202258/  You don't remove anything; you only add four lines.

Comment: Ok. I think it worked? I posted an edit at the bottom of my question.

Comment: So I should not expect to see it in "additional drivers"? I still get "No proprietary drivers are being used". Is there somewhere that will tell me it installed correctly?  Thanks

Comment: Additional Drivers will not help. You know it's installed correctly if it connects properly. You will need to recompile when Update Manager intalls a later kernel version.

Comment: So as it turns out, this actually did not work. I still have disconnects today. It's acting the same as it did before I went through all this.

Comment: Your question was how to compile the driver. We succeeded. I think you need to ask a new question about disconnections.

Comment: Ok?  The first paragraph of my OP clearly states the disconnects being the reason for this entire post. The steps I've followed up with were from suggestions on other threads,  which were not known to be a fix.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse chili555, can I get help installing this but for the rtl8723ae driver? I get 2 errors and does not seems to work fine.

Comment: Have you gone to the link I posted above "ubuntu forums.org" thread. The link is in the second post by Verunda. Then click on the download link that is closest to your region.

Comment: I am having trouble finding the link, is it on this thread? (Sorry I am new here) *Found it, thanks I will reply back if it works.

Comment: I do not find my driver, mine is rtl8723ae and it is not there.

Comment: At this point you're going to have to start a NEW question. Click on " Ask Question" button in the top/right. I'll try to help you from there. But we can't use the comment section here for troubleshooting ( forum rules)

Comment: Ok, post is done.