# Wireless Network is not Recognized

Tags: installation, networking

First of all, I am very new to Linux (as will be obvious).

I just purchased a new Tosiba Satellite laptop with Window 8 installed. I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.04.2 to a CD and when I boot to the CD, I have the choice to run Ubuntu or install it. I have tried to install it but it needs an internet connection. If I run it, it seems to work except that it does not detect the existence of a wireless network, which works just fine in Windows 8. I would like to install Ubuntu and replace Windows 8 entirely but I'm afraid that I'll still not be able to connect to the network and I will have lost Windows 8 (my only connection the the internet on this computer).

I saw a suggestion to use the lspci command so I tried it. I don't know how to copy the output to a file so I re-typed the result, as follows:

lspci -nn | grep 0280

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)

Then, I saw the suggestion:

```
Please get a temporary ethernet connection and open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and do:

sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43

Detach the ethernet and your wireless should now be working.
```

but this looks like it is specific to the network controller.

I followed the advice I found in other answers to internet connection issues and downloaded the new Realtec driver for Linux (linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013.tar.bz2) but I don't know what to do with it. If I somehow run this file, will I have access to the internet? If I do, I think I can install Ubuntu and replace Windows 8.

My second question is: How do I get output from the terminal into a file so I can add it to a question? Thanks so much for your help.

My second question is: How do I get output from the terminal into a file so I can add it to a question? Thanks so much for your help.

---

I have executed the command:

```
tar xvjf linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013.tar.bz2
```

Now I have several folders and lots of files. I have read the 'Readme' file but I still don't know what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

---

Yes, I have an Ethernet connection through which I could connect to the internet, I think. Should I try that and do a complete replace and install?

Comment: Just a simple question, does your laptop lacks of Ethernet JR45 ports? I mean, the one that you can connect with internet using cable.

Comment: Yes, I have an Ethernet connection through which I could connect to the internet, I think. Should I try that and do a complete replace and install?

Comment: Did you do what the suggestion *suggest*? Connect an ethernet cable and run those commands on the terminal. Do this after the installation for better results. Also check http://askubuntu.com/q/205575/169736 http://askubuntu.com/q/298303/169736 and http://askubuntu.com/q/298303/169736

Comment: I did not run those commands because they seem to be specific for the network controller described in the original question. My controller is a different make and model. Would the EXACT same commands work for my controller? @Braiam

Comment: Actually they are general for a whole bunch of Realtek cards.

Answer (score 1):

Please hook up the ethernet and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
cd rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8192ce
```

Your wireless should now be working.